# Retrieving the object from a replicated row with Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: database, object, laravel, eloquent, replicate

I'm replicating a database row and want to return the new row as an object.

```
$new_foo = Foo::find($id)->replicate()->save();
print_r($new_foo);
```

This returns 1 instead of the new object I just created. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you are actually saving the value returned from the `save()` method and not the replicated model.

You need to make a slight change to your code to save the replicated model into `$new_foo`

```
$new_foo = Foo::find($id)->replicate();
$new_foo->save();
dd($new_foo);
```

[save()](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L1451) method returns `boolean`.

Comment: Do you know why it needs to be on a new line? I've known that previously but I can't see it stated in docs why it has to be that way.

Comment: @JoeyB because ``replicate()`` method returns created object, and ``save()`` method returns ``boolean``.

Comment: It does seem a little counter-intuitive. Thanks!